# Selenium async script in own thread blocks other scripts

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, selenium, asynchronous

I have this scenario:

Different scripts have to be executed within the browser. On of them is to send a message from one browser to another (WebRTC). I want to measure the delay of each operation, sending messages in particular.

To achieve that I have created an own thread for each selenium driver, which is executing the scripts. Furthermore I have created **another** thread that is waiting for messages to arrive at the observed browser from other browsers. The thread which waits for the messages executes an asynchronous script like this:

```
String message = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
 "window.receivedMessage = function(message_id){" +
                                  "arguments[arguments.length - 1](message_id);" +
                           "}");
```

As you see I am waiting for a callback that is called, if a browser receives a message.

Unfortunatelly, this blocks every other script I want to be executed after this async script is registered in the browser (doesn't matter if .executeScript() or .executeAsyncScript() ).

Does someoe have an idea how to constantly waiting for messages to arrive AND execute other script with a webdriver?

**EDIT**

By the way: busy waiting shouldn't be the solution. I would prefer a way to notify selenium somehow that an operation is done, without constantly polling the result from the driver.

Comment: Do you have any option to verify the message has been received on the browser UI?

Comment: @QVSJ Do you mean if I have access to the browser that receives the message? Yes. I can modify the code of the browser, too.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue @firsti

Comment: @Seraph sorry for the late reply. I changed the setup to use an external message logging server. In the end of the program I just collect the difference between send-timestamp and receive-timestamp. Selenium does not support multithreading when executing scripts in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store the messages in a global variable and handle them once the other scripts are executed. Here is an example:

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// set a listener for the messages
js.executeScript(
    "window._asyncResult = [];                        " +
    "window.receivedMessage = function(message_id) {  " +
    "  window._asyncResult.push(message_id);          " +
    "};                                               " );

// send a message asynchroniously every second
js.executeScript(
    "window._asyncTimer = setInterval(function(){     " +
    "  window.receivedMessage(Math.random());         " +
    "}, 1000);                                        " );

// wait for 5 messages and return the list
List messages = (ArrayList)js.executeAsyncScript(
    "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];  " +
    "(function fn(){                                  " +
    "  if(window._asyncResult.length > 5) {           " +
    "    clearInterval(window._asyncTimer);           " +
    "    return callback(window._asyncResult);        " +
    "  }                                              " +
    "  setTimeout(fn, 30);                            " +
    "})();                                            " );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think that doesn't work for me. I've tried it and the script is still getting blocked by the AsyncScript. The problem is mainly that it seems that two scripts cannot be executed parallely with a driver. Even if one of them would be a AsyncScript and just a function which is waiting to be called. The driver seems to still wait for the callback, before it executes the following scripts.